# Damped oscillation experiment - damped harmonic motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, dissipation

Does anyone know of any easy experiments to do that involves damped spring harmonic motion? Preferably an experiment in which I vary variable A and examine how it affects variable B.

I was thinking of attaching a mass to a spring and then submerge the system in water. If I pull the mass down 10 cm, the spring will expand. When I release the mass, it will start oscillating in the water. Because of damping, the amplitude will get smaller and smaller and eventually reach zero. For the second trial, I will increase the mass attached to the spring and repeat the experiment. For the third trial, I will increase the mass even more, repeat the experiment and so on...
Essentially, I change the mass and examine how it affects the amplitude curve of the damped motion.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Why in water? It would work in air as well, although then it is more difficult to separate damping due to friction against the air, and due to the internal processes in the spring.

Comment: Yes I can perform it in air instead. Also, would it be interesting to examine how the period of one oscillation is affected when the mass is increased?

Comment: I think yes - the spring is not massless, so the theoretical equations would be closer to the truth, if the attached mass is much heavier than the mass of the spring.

Comment: A popular variation (at physics conference dinners) is a wine glass - if one taps it with a spoon, would it have higher pitch when it is full or when empty?